# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, gcdwebserver

I put the m3u8 in GCDWebServer to play. When I use Wi-Fi, it is no problem. But using 4G, appears this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unwrap optionals safely by using `if let `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved the problem.When I use 4 g, access to the **dataServer!ServerURL** is **nil**.My solution is to give it a local IP

```
 if davServer?.serverURL == nil {
                serverAddress = NSURL.init(string: "http://localhost/playts.m3u8")!
            }else{
               serverAddress = (davServer?.serverURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.m3u8!))!
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are force unwrapping `m3u8` in your code. If that's ever `nil`, you're going to have a problem. You're saying that it will never be nil when you force unwrap using that `!`.

You can use the `if let` approach, or you can test for `nil` too.

```
// Are you sure dataServer isn't nil too here?
if let serverAddress = dataServer!.serverURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.m3u8) {
    //Should be safe
}
```

Or

```
if m3u8 == nil {
    print("m3u8 is nil")
    return
}
```